# Average distance across a shape

Tags: calculus, geometry

Define a *shape* to be a closed non-self intersecting curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

> Is there a general formula for the average distance across a shape?

Let $\square$ denote the shape in question, with $\Delta$ the diagonal of $\square\times\square$,  and define $$f:\square\times\square\setminus\Delta\to\mathbb{R}^+$$ $$(a,b)\mapsto||b-a||.$$
Then I believe I'm asking for $$\frac{1}{V}\int_{\square\times\square\setminus\Delta}f\ \partial w\ \partial x\ \partial y\ \partial z$$ for an appropriate notion of 'volume' $V$, where $w,x,y$ and $z$ are the four dimensions we can move in (the 4D mean value theorem probably applies here).

This came up while thinking about dicing cilantro for potato soup; I'm curious how much extra perimeter is gained with each additional knife chop, on average, if I'm not paying attention to my chops.

Comment: Looks good to me. $V$ should be the volume of $\square\times\square\setminus{\Delta}$.